# Hyperledger support for python contract

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum

I could not find any sample snippets or tutorials related to deploying an executable python-based smart contract on hyperledger. Is this even possible? I'm looking for some guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the current smart contract languages are Go and Java.  Python has an SDK to allow a Python application to be Fabric client, but not smart contract implementation language.